# Using git with a website that has user uploads

Tags: php, git, github, web

okay i'll explain my issue short:

I have a website, lets say a board where user can chat and upload avatars, images, files etc.

I want to use git with this website.

So what i did:

- created a repo with bitbucket
- clone this repo local
- adding a .gitignore file (see below)
- copied my website to my local repo
- made a first commit
- push everything to bitbucket

Bitbucket now has my website, but without my ignored files and folders

my **.gitignore** looks like this (e.g):

```
uploades/user/avatars
cache/
logs/
```

Okay next step:

- I'm logging in with ssh to my webserver
- clone the bitbucket repo

Now my website is online without any user files (uploades, images, files etc...)
So if a user now uploades something in the git ignored folders i want the files to remain.

When i make local php changes and push it again to bitbucket and then do a "git pull" on my webserver all user files are deleted.

What do i miss? What is the best procedure?

Comment: ssh to server and manually create uploades folder. You don't want uploades folder to be in git. I assume it doesn't have any code, and all it has is user content - so just leave in on the server.

Comment: wait, when i do a clone on my webserver and then add via ssh the directory, lets say, **uploads/** this directory will never be deleted, when i do **git pull**?

Comment: No it won't (if I understand you correctly). That's how I do it too. Why don't you try, and see how it goes. I create bare repo on the server, and push to remote repo. Once remote repo (which is outside my public directory) is up to date, I goto my public directory (public_html) and `git clone` from my other remote repo. Works like a charm.

Comment: yes already done it, it works like a charm :)

Comment: Are you sure your code doesn't remove these files? Git shouldn't touch untracked files unless you do `git clean`. Were those files tracked before you added them to the .gitignore? Can you reproduce the issue again now that you added the gitignore? (Could it be that the first time they were deleted precisely because you had a commit removing them before the commit adding the .gitignore?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSH to the server and manually create `uploades` folder. You don't want `uploades` folder to be in git. I assume it doesn't have any code, and all it has is user content - so just leave in on the server.

This is how I push my local repo to a remote live server: I create a bare repo on the server, and push local repo to remote repo (on local add origin as remote). Once remote repo (which is outside my public directory) is up to date, I go to my public directory (public_html) and git clone from my other remote repo. Works like a charm.

**First time setup: send local repo to remote server**

1. On remote server create bare repo:

`git init --bare myproject.git`

2. On my local machine:

`git remote add origin user@ip:sshport/git_path_of_bare_repo/myproject.git`

3. Send local changes to remote bare repo

`git push origin master`

4. On the remote server, login into your public directory (public_html, or /var/www/, or whatever your document root is):

`git clone /path/to/your/bare/repo/above/myproject.git`

5. Inside your public directory, create whatever folders you need (uploads, logs, tmp, whatever). Further git pulls will not delete these folders.

That's it!

**Sending further updates from local to remote**
From your local machine just type:

`git push origin master`

Now your local changes are on your remote repo. On your server go to your public directory (step#4 above), and pull updates:

`git pull`

Works for me perfectly.